# How can you break an NSMutableAttributedString init?

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

We are looking to find a case that would cause NSMutableAttributedString to fail when loaded with HTML.  Have tried javascript, horrid HTML, etc, and it always just puts an error in the string.

We are assuming that there is an error state because the function can throwlet

```
attributedString = try? NSMutableAttributedString(data: htmlData ?? Data(),
                                                          options: options,
                                                          documentAttributes: nil)
```

Comment: Are you asking this out of curiosity, or because it might impact your use-case of this method? The method can throw for reasons beyond HTML parsing — for instance, the `data` you pass in doesn't need to be HTML data necessarily, but any one of the [supported formats](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/documenttype), and you can try to force reading as a specific format by passing in the [`.documentType`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/documentattributekey/1533961-documenttype) option key.

Comment: The method would throw if, for instance, you attempted to force `NSMutableAttribtuedString` to read in data as RTF data, but pass in something else entirely. More info on your use-case and what you're trying to find out might help give a more specific answer.

Comment: We were hoping that if we passed in invalid HTML it would throw an error, but that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: Ah. Unfortunately, I don't believe you can force this method to fail if the data is invalid in that way. Is your HTML arbitrary input, or are you looking to validate internal resource data? (Theoretically, you could load the HTML into a `WKWebView` and add message handlers for errors, but things start getting pretty finicky there...)